# Xcode 5 Expected identifier or '("

Tags: xcode, identifier

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Col10
//
//  Created by  on 6/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 ___FULLUSERNAME___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize swagLabel;
-(IBAction)swagTurtle:(id)sender {
swagLabel.text = @"Swag Turtle"; }

{; UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Hello!"
                        message:@"Please press Ok to finish"
                        delegate:nil
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [[message show]] }



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I tried looking up what I did wrong but I need help, I don't know what Expected identifier or '(' means. Please help me I've been trying to fix this problem for at least an hour now and I just started Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

ugh.. format your code better and you will see what is going on:

```
 -(IBAction)swagTurtle:(id)sender
 {
    swagLabel.text = @"Swag Turtle";
 }

{;
     UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Hello!"
                        message:@"Please press Ok to finish"
                        delegate:nil
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [[message show]]
}
```

Comment: To format code just select it and then control-I (that is the letter after H).

Comment: if that is all supposed to be one method, then remove the closing brace and the crazy semicolon